# Accessing value of onblur(this)

Tags: javascript

I am reading this small piece of code:

```
<td id="1095" class="i" bgcolor="" title="input1">
<input type="key" onblur="onBE(this);" name="1095" title="input1">
</td>
```

I am trying to learn & figure out how to read this key value. Input field has a value but it is masked and blurred. Inspect element shows above code.

Edit1: I am reviewing this code via Firebug
Edit2: There are 2 parts to my question -

1. Onblur is used. [Solved]
2. The value is masked. How to read this value?

The first answer solved onblur point.
Need to know how to reading masked value

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<td id="1095" class="i" bgcolor="" title="input1">
  <input type="key" onblur="onBE(this);" name="1095" title="input1">
</td>
<script>
  var onBE = function(e) {
    e.type = "text";
    alert(e.value);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thnx. But I cannot edit the page. I should have clear. I am inspecting this via firebug.

Comment: @Sunshine Try putting this in the console. `document.querySelectorAll('input[name="1095"]')[0].value;`

Comment: Your first alert query worked fine. Now when I select the input value in the text box and right click - inspect element, it pops up an alert box. Thnx. The issue is the value is masked ***** .

Comment: Try changing the type of the input element into text? In the onBE function, add `e.type = "text";`

Comment: Got it. I tried both with & w/o e.type='text'; Both are good.! Thanks much!